# Wild card SSL not working on subdomain pointed to different server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

This could be possibly a duplicate question, but I've tried every solution I found and nothing worked. On main domain, I've successfully installed SSL and it is working fine. I need to install the same **wild card SSL** on other two instances which are using **for subdomain**.

The overall structure I've setup so far is as follows -

1. Cloudflare is using for CDN where I've created A record for all 3 instances. One for main domain and other 2 for subdomains.
2. Created 3 instances **(Ubuntu 18.04 + Apache) on AWS EC2**

When I am hitting subdomain in browser, it is showing lock sign but with `Error 521 : Web server is down`

[image]

but When I am trying it with default Public DNS, it is showing my page without any error.

[image]

Please suggest what is missing here. Thanks much!!

Comment: Are you accessing as HTTP in the browser when you test directly?

Comment: Yes @ChrisWilliams - I am accessing as HTTP with default Public DNS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this answer gave me a hint [How to install third-party SSL Certificate with AWS EC2 Instance (Ubuntu AMI)? Will it cost one-time or monthly basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581061/how-to-install-third-party-ssl-certificate-with-aws-ec2-instance-ubuntu-ami-w)

And I resolved this error as follow -

**1. Downloaded the certificate files from primary server**

[image]

**2. Uploaded the same certificate files to the secondary server where the subdomain is pointed**

**3. then edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf file on secondary server, search for "SSLCertificate" and change the following lines**

[image]

**4. Enable the SSL configuration, and restart the webserver.**

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
apachectl configtest
apachectl graceful
```

Comment: I have done all changes but still the old SSL is showing is this mandatory to restart the ec2 instance?

Comment: @kantsverma - Have you restarted web server?

Comment: Yes after restart it work thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [521 error from CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003011431-Troubleshooting-Cloudflare-5XX-errors#521error) indicates that it is unable to speak to your host on that port.

> Error 521 occurs when the origin web server refuses connections from Cloudflare. Security solutions at your origin may block legitimate connections from certain Cloudflare IP addresses.
>
> The two most common causes of 521 errors are:
>
> - Offlined origin web server application
> - Blocked Cloudflare requests

Please check the following:

- The EC2 security group is allowing inbound access on both port 80/443 (this cannot be locked down to your IP address).
- If a NACL is in place (which is not the default one) ensure that both the communication ports (80/443) and the [ephemeral ports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports) are open.
- Ensure that the servers are listening on both port 80/443.

It is important to identify whether CloudFlare it attempting to connect to HTTP or HTTPS, it can support both of these models based on the configuration.

If you're still stuck after these points you can attempt to validate the requests going to your server using [VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've already enabled and checked inbound rules for both port 80 and 443

Comment: Have you checked the other points? This error can only be an issue with it trying to establish a TCP connection on the port, I suspect if security groups are open it's trying to connect to HTTPS and finding either its not listening or the SSL is invalid for it. :)

Comment: I have verified it again and the server is listening port 443. I am not sure but do I need to configure SSL on subdomain server too? When I am hitting IP address of subdomain server, it is redirecting to main domain instead of showing web page from subdomain.

Comment: If the DNS record is hitting the subdomain server and there is no SSL, yes you would need to add it :) I added a link to VPC flow logs. If you enable this on the server the record resolves to you should be able to identify traffic coming inbound to the server :)

Comment: Can you please share any link about how can I add SSL on subdomain pointing to different server?

Comment: The SSL simply needs to exist on the server that receives the request. SSL will be evaluated before the redirect occurs. As long as you have an SSL for that subdomain on the server it will allow the request to occur.

Comment: In some article, I found that I need to generate KEY and CSR from the main domain server and use it on subdomain server, but it didn't explain how to do that.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a tool such as certbot: https://certbot.eff.org